# Use MSQL Server CTE to return all Parents

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the below table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Areas](
                       [AreaID] [bigint],
                       [ParentArea] [bigint] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Areas] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

```
INSERT INTO Areas (AreaID,ParentArea) VALUES (142,null);
INSERT INTO Areas (AreaID,ParentArea) VALUES (143,142);
INSERT INTO Areas (AreaID,ParentArea) VALUES (144,143);
INSERT INTO Areas (AreaID,ParentArea) VALUES (148,144);
```

The target is to return all parents per specific AreaID:
Example: AreaID = 148

```
AreaID      1st       2nd        3rd       4th
--------------------------------------------------------
 148        144       143        142       NULL
```

I tried the below query and it gives result up to 2nd.

```
WITH  descendant 
   AS (SELECT  AreaID AS AreaID,
               ParentArea
         FROM  [dbo].[Areas]
        WHERE  AreaID = 148

 UNION ALL

       SELECT  t.AreaID,
               t.ParentArea
         FROM .[dbo].[Areas] t
         JOIN descendant d
           ON t.ParentArea = d.AreaID
       )

       SELECT d.AreaID AS descen_id1,
              d.ParentArea AS first_parent,
              a.ParentArea AS second_parent
         FROM  descendant d
         JOIN [dbo].[Areas] a
           ON d.ParentArea = a.AreaID
```

```
AreaID       1st       2nd
---------------------------
148          144       143`
```

Comment: The fact you want to do this with columns means you need to `PIVOT` after; I'd strongly suggest against that and return your results in rows. If you don't have a explicit number of parents (always 5) then you'll need dynamic SQL, and this gets very messy. Leave the pivoting for the presentation layer, not the SQL layer.

Comment: Yes, there is not always explicit number of parents (max. is 5).

Comment: In that case write a query that returns the parents as *rows* that include the level and pivot the results on the client. A more complex solution would be to assume up to 5 or 7 levels, then PIVOT on the Level field.

Answer (score 1):

If the maximum number of parents is always 5, then:

```
select a.AreaID, a.ParentArea as [1st], a2.ParentArea as [2th], a3.ParentArea as [3th], a4.ParentArea as [4th]
from Areas a
left join Areas a2 ON a2.AreaID = a.ParentArea
left join Areas a3 ON a3.AreaID = a2.ParentArea
left join Areas a4 ON a4.AreaID = a3.ParentArea
left join Areas a5 ON a5.AreaID = a4.ParentArea
where a.AreaID = 148
```

Result :

| AreaID | 1st | 2th | 3th | 4th |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 148 | 144 | 143 | 142 | null |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/5Yz3ChmL)